# Incorporate asymptote environment into macro

Tags: macros, verbatim, asymptote

I'm trying to write a macro (ideally an environment, but a command would do) that takes a piece of Asymptote code, displays it in a `verbatim` environment, and then runs it through an `asy` environment. Unfortunately, my every attempt at the latter seems to go wrong. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\newcommand{\asycode}[1]{\begin{asy}
#1
\end{asy}}
\begin{document}
\asycode{label("$x^2 = x \cdot x$");}
\end{document}
```

If I attempt to compile this, I get the following:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> problem.tex

?
```

What am I doing wrong here, and can it be fixed in any remotely reasonable fashion?

[Note: I've tried a number of different permutations regarding line break placement, etc., and none of them seem to work.]

Comment: Try using the command-form of the `asy` environment. For example, `\newcommand{\asycode}[1]{\asy #1\endasy}`.

Comment: @Werner: That doesn't help. For that matter, even putting `\asy` and `\endasy` in the actual document does not work. As far as I can tell from the source, the environment keeps going with `\next` until it encounters the string `\end{asy}`.

Comment: The problem is that the `asy` environment writes line by line; the line is absorbed using the end-of-line as delimiter; by hiding the environment in a macro, it's impossible to make the needed category code change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `asy` environment writes the output file line by line; each line is absorbed using the end-of-line as delimiter. By hiding the environment in a macro, it's impossible to make the needed category code change. When an argument to a macro has been read, category codes are assigned, so they can't be changed any more. In particular, the information about line breaks, which `asy` relies on, is irremediably lost

You can do by emulating the `asy` environment's working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\asycode[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{asy}%
  \setkeys{ASYkeys}{#1}%
  \ifASYattach
    \ASYinlinefalse
  \fi
  \ifx\asydir\empty\else
    \def\ASYprefix{\asydir/}%
  \fi
  \immediate\write\AsyPreStream{%
    \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{%
      \ASYprefix\noexpand\jobname-\the\c@asy.pre}{}{}%
  }
  \asy@write@graphic@header
  \immediate\write\AsyStream{\detokenize{#2}}% here asy does the writing
  \asy@finalise@stream
  \asy@input@graphic
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\asycode{label("$x^2 = x \cdot x$");}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This certainly does what I wanted. But even including your comment above, I still don't entirely understand why my original MWE doesn't work. How exactly does hiding the environment in a macro prevent changing category codes?

Comment: @CharlesStaats When an argument to a macro is read, category codes are assigned, so they can't be changed any more. In particular, the information about line breaks is irremediably lost.

Comment: @egreg: There is a problem. When your `\asycode` contains blank lines `\par` tokens appear in the `asy` file. Then Asymptote crashes.

Comment: @user125730 Sorry, but that's essentially unavoidable.

Comment: I found out that this is avoidable when I make `\^^M` active and define it as `\newline` before any `\asycode`. I add the line `\catcode'\^^M=\active \let\^^M\newline`. But when I add this to the definition of `\asycode`, it does not work any more. I don't understand that... Do you know the reason? Or maybe how to fix this?